# How can I set value of MutableLiveData<Boolean>() as adverse in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

`_displayCheckBox` is a `MutableLiveData<Boolean>`, I hope to set it as adverse.

But It seems that `_displayCheckBox.value =  !_displayCheckBox.value!!`  can't work well, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
private val _displayCheckBox = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(true)
val displayCheckBox : LiveData<Boolean> = _displayCheckBox

fun switchCheckBox(){
    _displayCheckBox.value =  !_displayCheckBox.value!!   //It seems that it can't work well.
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it can't work well"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wrap the set value with a scope function such as `let`, you'd be able to negate the value only if it is not null, otherwise, the negation would be ignored.

```
fun switchCheckBox() {
    _displayCheckBox.value?.let {
        _displayCheckBox.value = !it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will transform the live data inverting the liveData value, it will observe `_displayCheckBox` and change its appling the `{!it}` operation to its value:

```
private val _displayCheckBox = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(true)
val displayCheckBox = Transformations.map(_displayCheckBox) { !it }
```

Note that you have to observe the value to trigger the updates:

**SomeActivity.kt**

```
displayCheckBox.observe(this, Observer {value -> 
    // Do something with the value 
})
```

Here is the docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#map(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20androidx.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20Y%3E)

Comment: Thanks! but I hope to invert  `_displayCheckBox` in the function `switchCheckBox()`

Comment: OH! I get it now, my bad, I will try to came up with something

Comment: how about  `_displayCheckBox.value =  _displayCheckBox.value?.not()` ?

Comment: Thanks! but your code is just like my code `!_displayCheckBox.value!!` , I think it will not work well.

Comment: It will remain null if the value is null an will invert it if the value isn't null

Comment: There's also an option to set a default value in case of a null such as `_displayCheckBox.value =  _displayCheckBox.value?.not() ?: true`  but this introduces a possible buggy scenario.

Comment: Thanks! but your code doesn't fit my goal. I hope to define a function to switch the value of `_displayCheckBox`. It's very simple if `_displayCheckBox` is normal Boolean variable, but now it's a `LiveData<Boolean>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```kotlin
fun switchCheckBox() = _displayCheckBox.value?.let { _displayCheckBox.postValue(!it) }
```

`postValue` will trigger the observer for `displayCheckBox`

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fan of using a `.let` in this scenario because that would preserve the null value of the LiveData which is obviously something you are intending to avoid. I would use the following:

```
fun toggleDisplayCheckBox() {
    _displayCheckBox.run { value = value == false }
}
```

This adheres to the following Boolean? mapping:

```
When the value is...
    true -> false
    false -> true
    null -> false
```

In the case where you want the value to be set to true instead of false when it is null, the following could be used instead:

```
fun toggleDisplayCheckBox() {
    _displayCheckBox.run { value = value != true }
}
```